# Net WebClient Encoding not working

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, webclient

I'm trying to parse an html document using the .NET WebClient but the characters I'm getting are not correct. I have configured lots of Encodings but I cant find why I´m getting it wrong:

The URL is http://www.vatican.va/archive/ESL0506/__P2.HTM.

This is my code (you can test it in a ConsoleApp)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
        var htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.vatican.va/archive/ESL0506/__P2.HTM");

        var splittedHtml = htmlCode.Split('<').ToList();

        var htmlVerses = splittedHtml.Where(x => x.StartsWith("p class=MsoNormal align=left")).ToList();
    }
```

Then, in htmlVerses I get strings like:

```
"p class=MsoNormal align=left style='margin-left:0cm;text-align:left;\ntext-indent:0cm'>3 Entonces Dios dijo: &laquo;Que\nexista la luz&raquo;. Y la luz existi&oacute;."
```

Check this part: `3 Entonces Dios dijo: &laquo;Que\nexista la luz&raquo;. Y la luz existi&oacute;`

Its not well parsed. It should be: `3 Entonces Dios dijo: «Que exista la luz». Y la luz existió.`

If we check the chrome source code we get this:

[image]

Then I tried to get the source code from http://www.generateit.net/seo-tools/source-viewer/ and I'm getting the same anomally as in my app.

Its really odd, the encoding that the web page use is charset=iso-8859-1, the same that my webclient uses.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a side node: don't use `htmlCode.Split('<').`. Use a real html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML escapes special characters for transmission, you need to convert them back.
Fortunately, .NET provides methods to automagically do that for you:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

If you are using .NET 4.5 then you can use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` instead, which is already included in System.Net (see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx))

Comment: Additionally, I would use `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` instead of hard-coding the codepage

Comment: Thats it! Im having now some wired escape characters (\n) but nothing i cant handle. About the encoding, I tried them both. Thanks